# core-js version is not updating in wappalyzer tool even after upgrading the angular version from 11 to 12

Tags: angular, core-js

we don't have core-js package in the package.json, we tried to install core-js library separately as the current version in wappalyzer tool was showing as deprecated. adding the package manually didn't work, then we have updated the angular version from 11 to 12 and checked the core-js version locally and in the local core-js version was updated to 3.16.0 but when we deployed the angular upgrade changes the core-js version was not updated, only the angular version was updated in the tool. What could be the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

clear the cache of the wappalyzer or re install it.